# What are the differences accross the regional version of Mega Man Battle Network Legacy Collection?

Tags: version-differences, mega-man-bn-legacy-collection

Long story short, it is 2023 and Capcom still hates Mega Man so when the Mega Man Battle Network Legacy Collection was released back in April for some unclear arbitrary reason Europe didn't get a physical version.

To evaluate the possibility of just getting the game from a different region I am comparing the various available versions of the game but some details are still unclear.

- Does the Japanese version of the game include the English language too? Some sources say it does, some it does not. Are there multiple versions?
- Does any of the version NOT include the actual game but just a download code? That would make a physical release just a borderline scam, but we are talking about Capcom and they already did that with the previous collections on Switch.
- The game should not have any DLC (that would probably be region-locked despite the console be region-free). Is there any other content that you would not be able to access when importing (online trading for example)? - this is not a given thing since some games allow normal online play even if imported (I think Pokemon does)
- Any other difference I am missing?
- Do every version include ***both*** the English and Japanese languages? Access to the Japanese language is needed to obtain Django  V3 in BN6 (see comment below)

Note that all of this questions are about the **physical** boxed release of the game, so please do not consider the downloadable e-shop version when answering.

---

**About the Django chip:**
Apparently the chip DjangoV3 in BN6 can be only obtained if the final VirusBattler fight is played while the language is set to Japanese. This is because some drops are changed based on the current language and there is no other way to get that chip (outside trading) otherwise.